# What is a good percentage value for SMOTE in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, java

I am using the oversampling technique named as SMOTE to balance my dataset in Weka. To balance my dataset I needed to use 1300 as my -p (percentage) value. The default -p (percentage) value is 100.

I am interested in knowing whether the -p (percentage) value I am using bad because it is a very big number compared with the default value? Does this unnecessarily affect the performance of the classification models constructed (I am using 10-fold cross validation to construct my models)?

I am happy to provide more details of my classification if needed :)